# Capture/export JOGL animation to video file

Tags: java, opengl, animation, video, jogl

How can I capture/export a JOGL animation to a video file? I know that I can use `glReadPixels()` to grab each frame via `PBO`, but is there some library/source code that I can find on the web? Or is there a better/faster way to do that without render the entire scene? And if I use the `glReadPixels()` method is there a different capture image size if I resize the window hosting the OpenGL Canvas?

I have already read the following articles:

- [Recording DirectX and OpenGL Rendered Animations](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15941/Recording-DirectX-and-OpenGL-Rendered-Animations)
- [Encode OpenGL to Video with OpenCV](http://tommy.chheng.com/2013/09/09/encode-opengl-to-video-with-opencv/)

PS: I need this software for Mac OS X.

Comment: Hi, I followed these tutorials to do the same : http://www.antongerdelan.net/opengl/videocapture.html unfortunately the source code is in C++, maybe consider taking a look at it and port it to Java?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've already done most of the work. I'm not sure if there is a commonly used lib somewhere but it might be more effort finding and using one than just implementing it.

When you say "faster way without rendering the entire scene", of course you need to render something to record it but if you want to view it at the same time, don't render twice. You can render via your FBO, then [`glBlitFramebuffer`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glBlitFramebuffer.xml) the image to the back buffer as well as using your `glReadPixels` to copy the result back to main memory for encoding.

Given encoding may take some time, it might be worth attempting to copy the result back asynchronously (some discussion [here](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/170511-Does-PBO-glGetTexImage-improve-the-performance)).

It's also pretty easy to write the images straight to disk and encode to video later with something such as ffmpeg, though of course not as convenient.

You'll have to resize the FBO attachments manually when your window resizes. Unless you're not using an FBO in which case I'm guessing jogl will resize the front/back buffers for you.

Comment: Ok. First thanks for your answer. I have understand that I have to render the entire scene/animation to a FrameBufferObject, then read it with glReadPixels, convert the ByteBuffer returned to a BufferedImage and then generate a video by using this bufferedImages. But the problem is now how to encode a video from bufferedImages? I know that there is the Xuggle lib, but it is distributed under the GPL Version 3 license and I need to distribute a commercial software! So did you know any other lib that I can use for encode the bufferedImages to video files?

Comment: AFAIK OpenCV and Theora are both BSD and cross platform.